# Get index of control located in e-th coordinates

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `flowLayoutPanel` on my form. I have some  controls there which can be dragged and dropped . What I need is to get the index of the control, which is located on mouse position, for example if mouse is on the first widget, I have to get 0. Please show me some way how can I do it.

Thanks

EDIT

Frogot to upload the photo ,sorry
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to iterate through the controls in the flowLayoutPanel.Controls collection to find which control is under the mouse. Then iterate through the list again to find how many controls are above/equal height and to the left of the control in question.

I don't think you can avoid the 2 iterations, as the ordering of the collection is not tied to physical position.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a 5-year old question, but since this question and answer still pop up in Google, I feel compelled to provide a genuine answer.

The FlowLayoutPanel class provides a method called GetChildAtPoint which takes a client-relative location and returns the control at that position (if the position is the mouse location relative to the FlowLayoutPanel window, then that identifies the control under the cursor). Worse case, then, you only have one linear search iteration through the FlowLayoutPanel's children to match objects (if in fact, your objective is to get the actual index instead of finding the index to look up the control; if finding the control is what you actually want, you are already done).

In my particular application, I needed to track things easily in a drag-drop scenario where a control could only be dragged within a range of related controls. So I used the "Tag" property to populate the index into the control itself as I was populating the panel (actually I stored a reference to the base class of my child control wrappers, and maintained the index in a base-class Property that I could query after casting the Tag to the base class, but I digress. The reference allowed me to get all kinds of cool information about the window under the cursor for appropriate display and/or manipulation in addition to maintaining the parent index).